# Having trouble exporting from an Angular2 module

Tags: angular, angular2-modules

I'm a beginner with Angular 2, and am trying to understand how to export a class from a feature module, and import it into my main module.

When I try to compile this in typescript, I receive the following two errors:

- app/app.component.ts(11,21): error TS2304: Cannot find name
  'AddService'.
- app/app.module.ts(4,9): error TS2305: Module
  '"C:/angular/app/add/arithmetic.module"' has no exported member
  'AddService'.

my tree is simple:

```
/
  index.html
  package.json
  systemjs.config.js
  tsconfig.json
  typings.json
  app/
     app.component.html
     app.component.ts
     app.module.ts
     main.ts
     add/
        add.service.ts
        arithmetic.module.ts
```

The interesting parts are below:

app.module.ts:

```
import {NgModule}      from '@angular/core';
import {BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser';
import {AppComponent}   from './app.component';

// this next line generates an error from typescript compiler:
// app/app.module.ts(4,9): error TS2305: Module
// '"C:/angular/app/add/arithmetic.module"' has no exported 
// member 'AddService'.

import {AddService} from './add/arithmetic.module';

@NgModule({
    imports:        [BrowserModule],
    declarations:   [AppComponent, AddService],
    bootstrap:      [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

app.component.ts

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {

    calculate() {
        // this next line generates the error:
        // app/app.component.ts(11,21): 
        // error TS2304: Cannot find name 'AddService'.
        var c = new AddService();

        var x = c.addTwoNumbers(3, 5);
        console.log(x);
    }
}
```

arithmetic.module.ts

```
import {NgModule}            from '@angular/core';
import {CommonModule}        from '@angular/common';
import {AddService}          from './add.service';

@NgModule({
  imports: [CommonModule],
  exports: [AddService]
})
export default class ArithemeticModule { }
```

add.service.ts

```
export class AddService {
    addTwoNumbers(a: number, b: number) : number {
        return a + b;
    } 
}
```

This really is frustrating because

1) I'm exporting AddService -- it's marked as 'export' and from within ArithmeticModule I'm marking it as exported using the @NgModule metadata.

2) I'm importing the [allegedly] exported AddService class from within my main module, so the AddService should be usable since it's exported from the ArithmeticModule

It works fine if I import the AddService directly from within the component, but that's not what I'm going for: I want to import the class from my main module, and utilize the exports from that module, just like we do for Angular's modules (e.g., BrowserModule and FormsModule). The documentation for @NgModule says that we should be able to do just that - import once from my feature module, into my main module, and then it's usable throughout the main module.

Can someone tell me what I'm doing wrong? Or am I misunderstanding what modules are supposed to be used for?

Comment: please share your AddService file

Comment: Are you lazy loading ArithemeticModule ?

Comment: user32: AddService file is above, as 'add.service.ts'
Dustin: not lazy loading.

Answer (score 12):

For services use `providers: [...]`, they will be added to the root injector (from non-lazy-loaded modules).

`exports: []` is for directives, components, and pipes and modules that export  directives, components, and pipes.

Comment: :D I try to start somewhere. Perhaps it leads to helpful responses, other error messages, ...

Answer (score 2):

There are couple of mistakes I can see from here,

1) If you want to use **AddService** everywhere, better to inject it in **AppModule** as shown below, (remove AddService from arithmetic.module)

```
 import {AddService} from './add/arithmetic.module';

 @NgModule({
    imports:        [BrowserModule],
    declarations:   [AppComponent, AddService],
    bootstrap:      [AppComponent],
    providers:      [AddService]          //<<<===here 
})
export class AppModule { }
```

2) service should be **injectable**

```
import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'; //<<<===here

@Injectable()                             //<<<===here
   export class AddService {
    addTwoNumbers(a: number, b: number) : number {
        return a + b;
    } 
   }
```

3) How to use in **app.component.ts**

```
import {AddService} from './add/arithmetic.module';
import { Component } from '@angular/core';    

@Component({
    selector: 'my-app',
    templateUrl: 'app/app.component.html'
})
export class AppComponent {
    constructor(private s:AddService){}   //<<<===here
    calculate() {

       // var c = new AddService();

        var x = s.addTwoNumbers(3, 5);     //<<<===here
        console.log(x);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks micronyks and Günter!  I'm confused about the comments. 

I now understand that by specifying the AddService as a provider, I can inject it into my component. But you also said to remove AddService from the arithmetic.module.ts file, which I don't understand because the code you supplied shows the service being imported from the module.

So I kept the AddService in the arithmetic module, and used the code as you specified, but I'm still getting an error for app.module.ts saying  arithmetic.module"' has no exported member 'AddService'.